# How to unschedule a choiced schedule method in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

follow is part of source.
it calls three times a schedule method.

I would like to unschedule a 2) schedule.

How to unschedule a choiced schedule method?

```
-(id) init
{ 
    if( (self=[super init] ))
    { 
        int_count=0;
        [self schedule:@selector(displayOne) interval:1.0]; 1) schedule
        [self schedule:@selector(displayOne) interval:2.0]; 2) schedule
        [self schedule:@selector(displayOne) interval:1.5]; 3) schedule
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no point in scheduling multiple selectors that call the same method.  If you look in your console window you will see a message saying this:

```
CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 1.00 to 2.00

CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 2.00 to 1.50
```

What you could do is schedule a selector with different method names like this:

```
[self schedule:@selector(displayOne) interval:1.0]; 1) schedule
[self schedule:@selector(displayTwo) interval:2.0]; 2) schedule
[self schedule:@selector(displayThree) interval:1.5]; 3) schedule
```

and in the `displayTwo` method have it unschedule itself like this:

```
[self unschedule:@selector(displayTwo)];
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. :-D

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to separate the schedulers into 3 different functions, instead of using the displayOne function.

With 3 different functions, you will be able to use the unschedule function. Right now, you can either unschedule them all, or leave them all running.

```
   [self unschedule:@selector(test1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

To unscheduled current running selector you can `_cmd` keyword as

```
[self unschedule:_cmd];
```